# Overwrite anaconda3 unsuccessful installation

Tags: anaconda3

I deleted the anaconda directory under the *home* and *bashrc* configurations.

Now, I need to install it again, but it occurs a problem evenif overwrites unsuccessful installation on Linux.

Should I delete some additional config files? How can I handle this?

```java
sh Downloads/Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh -u -p /home/user/anaconda3/
```

```java
PREFIX=/home/user/anaconda3
Unpacking payload ...
concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback:                                                           
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 384, in wait_result_broken_or_wakeup
  File "multiprocessing/connection.py", line 256, in recv
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
'''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "entry_point.py", line 69, in <module>
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 559, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 608, in result_iterator
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 445, in the result
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 390, in __get_result
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
[8382] Failed to execute script entry_point
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure deleted **.conda** directory under *home* and have enough **disk space**.

No need to delete **.cache** or any **bin** libraries.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).